# Applet and session timeout on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, applet, session-timeout

I've got an applet served by an ColdFusion/ASP.NET web site. Every time the user interacts with the applet, I request a small ASP.Net page (.aspx file). I get it fine (the processed html, not the raw .aspx). I thought that was all I had to do to keep the ASP.NET session alive, but it doesn't work. The session dies just as though none of that occurred.

I have access to the session id and I include it as a cookie in the request. I know it's correct because the applet also uses services on the server and those services get the correct session object.

I don't have any other request properties (other than cookies) in the request for the web page. Should I add, maybe Referrer? or Connection? (which I thought was just TCP/IP related). Or is there something else I should do?

Comment: Are you calling anything from session in your ASPX page?  If not then the session timeout is not reset.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current understanding: First, the problem wasn't the session time out. It was the authorization time out. The authorization cookie is an encryption of a "Forms Authorization Ticket". The ticket contains the expiration time. No copy of the ticket is kept on the server. When the ticket is "about" to expire (more than half-way through the time out period), a new ticket is issued and an encrypted version is sent as a response cookie. I have not been looking for that cookie.

At least, that's what I think is happening.